# Export multiple Angular ng-grids to an Excel file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

i have 7 grids and i need to export them to an Excel file. It can be done putting each one on a sheet or all of them in the same sheet but I don't have a single clue in how to achieve this.

Can someone give me an advise?

Comment: Please do some research into creating excel files and when you have some real live code problems you will get plenty of help then. There are libraries available for both client and server. Question is just far too broad currently

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the data from grids into arrays, then use .join function to make strings from arrays, to convert it to CSV format. It is not the main .xls(x) format, but close enough.

For example, if you have an array:

```
var myArray = ["Peter", "21", "2005"]
var myString = myArray.join(",")
```

Then myString will be "Peter,21,2005", which is exactly [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Now just open the file with excel and you have it.